# Validar CPF com Ajax e em seguida enviar o formulário

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boa Noite, Pessoal.
Estou precisando de ajuda, estou tentando fazer uma validação e em seguida enviar o fomulário, o que eu preciso basicamente é:
Quando o usuário digitar o CPF no formulário, quero fazer uma verificação no banco de dados, caso o cpf não esteja cadastrado, o formulário e enviado, caso contrário e mostrado uma mensagem na mesma página.

```
            <form method="post" action="pesquisa.php" id="formulario">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf"  maxlength="14" placeholder="Digite o seu CPF" required>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idade">Idade:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idade" name="idade" placeholder="Digite sua Idade" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="M"> <span class="label-text">Masculino </span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="F"> <span class="label-text">Feminino </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-info" id="enviar">Iniciar Pesquisa</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="false" id="validado" name="validado">
        </form>
```

O Javascript está assim:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(e){
var cpf = $("#cpf").val();

if(validarCPF(cpf)){
    buscarCPF(cpf);
}else{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#cpf").val('');
    $("#cpf").focus();
    return false;
}    
});
function buscarCPF(cpf){
var req;

cpf = cpf.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var url = "busca.php?cpf="+cpf;
req.open("Get", url, true); 

req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(req.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Buscando CPF...';
    }

    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        var resposta = req.responseText;
        if(resposta != ""){
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>CPF Já Cadastrado!</div>";
        }
    }
}
req.send(null);
```

}

O Problema e que não sei como que eu faço pro submit só executar caso não seja retornado nenhum dado na pesquisa, tentei utilizar if, porem pelo que eu andei lendo a pesquisa no banco é feita de forma assicrona, então o formulário e enviado, tem como submeter o form apenas depois de efetuar a pesquisa no banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que está fazendo, precisa dar um nome ao formulário:

```
<form method="post" action="pesquisa.php" id="formulario" name="formulario">
```

Colocar o `e.preventDefault();` fora do `if`:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
..
```

E colocar um `else` no retorno do Ajax para submeter o formulário::

```
if(resposta != ""){
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>CPF Já Cadastrado!</div>";
}else{
   document.formulario.submit();
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, deu certinho. Muito Obrigado!